# Finding the closed form for $x_n^2 = -x_{n-1}^2+6x_{n-2}^2+n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I'm trying to find a closed form for the recurrence relation $x_n^2 = -x_{n-1}^2+6x_{n-2}^2+n$, with $x_1 = \frac{1}{4}, x_2=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}$ and $x_i \in \mathbb R^+$. 
My attempt was to let $z_n=x_n^2$ and then transform the recurrence relation to a 2nd order non-homogeneous linear recurrence relation. Substitution gives:
$$z_n = -z_{n-1}+6z_{n-2}$$.

Now the above recurrence relation has complementary function $$z'_n = L2^n +K(-3)^n$$ for $L,K$ arbitrary constants. 
I also found that the new recurrence relation has a particular solution given by 
$$z''_n = \frac{11-n}{4}$$.

Thus the general solution is $$z_n = L2^n +K(-3)^n + \frac{11-n}{4}$$
By substitution I then found $L=\frac{-7}{8}, K = \frac{11}{48}$. So the unique solution for our recurrence relation is: $$z_n = \frac{-7}{8}2^n +\frac{11}{48}(-3)^n + \frac{11-n}{4}$$ Now, for $n=3$ I obtain a negative value of $z_n$ indicating that my solution is invalid. I've checked my solution numerous times and I'm pretty sure my numbers are right so I'm wondering if my method here is wrong.

Comment: You need also to make squaring.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg made squaring?

Comment: For example, $z_1=\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I already did that in my solution.

Comment: Your particular solution is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this particular solution instead $z''_n = -\dfrac{n}{4}-\dfrac{11}{16}$, the one you used does not work.

Comment: I don't understand why mine won't work though. I let my particular solution be $z_n^{''} = an + b$ and by substitution to the linear non-homogeneous recurrence relation I found $a=\frac{-1}{4}, b=\frac{11}{4}$.

Comment: Nevermind I just realised I had badly substituted.

Comment: :) In any case you did a good work.